# jQuery 1.8 Ajax Request type "HEAD" returns null xhr object on success but worked in 1.7

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I seem to have found an undocumented breaking change in jQuery 1.8.3.

While upgrading a page from jQuery 1.7 to 1.8.3 one of our ajax calls of type "HEAD" stopped working.

Upon debugging the success callback is fired but the parameter, "xhr" is null when I use the google CDN to run the page in jQuery 1.8.3.

If I switch back to 1.7 the xhr object is fully operational and not null.

I have scoured google and jQuery site for breaking changes in 1.8.* but can find nothing on point. I need to upgrade this as another library I need to use requires the latest jQuery so I am now between a rock and a hard place.

Code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: pth + b,
    error: function (xhr) {

    // always succeeds

    },
    success: function (xhr) {
        // in jQuery 1.7.0 ONLY xhr is a non-null object - 1.8.3/1.9.0 receive a null object as a parameter
        c = xhr.getResponseHeader('x-amz-meta-mix');
        if (c == null) c = b;

    }
});
```

Thanks!

PS- I should add that in Fiddler the response is always 200 and the information I am looking for is always present. The issue is that the xhr object is null if I do not use jQuery 1.7.0 in favor of 1.8.3 or 1.9.0

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with 1.9 but it made no difference. Something seems to have changed between 1.7.0 and 1.8.3 and beyond...

Comment: To help narrow things down: is this a cross-origin request?

Comment: This is same domain request. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? (StackOverflow posts should always follow a Q&A format, so...)

Comment: My question is why is the xhr object returned null in my success callback.

Comment: Is `xhr` null or is `xhr.getResponseHeader('x-amz-meta-mix')` null? That is, do you get an null-reference exception for trying to access `getResponseHeader` on a null `xhr`?

Comment: The xhr object is null. The object parameter itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that jQuery has changed the format of the [`success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). In 1.8 and later it is:

> Type: Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

The `jqXHR` is now the third argument, rather than the first, so change your `success` handler to:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    ...
```

Comment: Wow... I tried to find anything on this and failed. You however succeeded and just ended my pain. This is the correct answer! Big thank you.